# How do I consume workflow outbound messages?

Tags: soap-api, c#, soap

I'm working on integrating a record update in Salesforce into a third party application.  My plan is to create a service using the ASP.NET Web API that listens for requests from Salesforce.  I'm having difficulty figuring out what exactly this request from Salesforce looks like.

It would be much easier if they just sent plain old form-style data, but, instead I have to inspect some chunk of ugly SOAP markup.

Does anyone have code samples they could provide on how to consume this outbound message?

Answer (score 3):

There's a C# sample right in the [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_listener.htm).

Answer (score 1):

When you create the outbound message in Salesforce, it gives you the option to download the WSDL. You should then be able to use a tool like [wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to create your .Net code. I don't have experience with this, but I've done something similar when creating an integration with Jitterbit.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to the Outbound Message in Salesforce, there is a link to generate the WSDL
You should be able to import this WSDL in VisualStudio to generate the consuming service.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_listener.htm